# how to partition/split range between two dates into week number (w1 , w2 , w3, w4, ...) in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

anyone here is able to help with this?

start_date = 1-1-2022
end_date = 2-2-2022
delta = end_date - start_dt
freq = 7d
need to generate a column as week number that breaks delta into relevant number of week (freq = 7d) with values as w1, w2, w3,...
Note: my dataset is huge with various start & end dates for each user, so it is not feasible to generate 'date_range' and then create a week_number from it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input data and expected output, as well as code for what you've tried based on your own research and a description of what went wrong with your attempts. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for help on creating your data sample.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows to get the unique enumeration of the weeks for your index.

```
df['week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index).isocalendar().week
```